# Twilio, how to get all message to OR from a phone number (either) in one query

Tags: twilio

I know I can easily query twilio to get all the message TO a phone number.
I know I can easily query twilio to get all the message FROM a phone number (like incoming phone numbers).

How do I do both at the same time?   Basically an OR operator on a list filter.

Example, I sent 555-555-5555 three SMS messages, and they replied four times.  How do I query to get all seven messages?

Also, I'm using twilio-php... thats not really important but just thought I'd let you know.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with Twilio's current API.  You'll need to do this in your application, with ksort and arrays, after you query both the from and to number.